# How to fetch sum of value in an object?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, ecmascript-6

```
"254": {
    "Term 1": {
        0: { id: 1, Students: 29 },
        1: { id: 1, Students: 20 },
        2: { id: 1, Students: 11 }
    },
    "Term 2": {
        0: { id: 1, Students: 9 },
        1: { id: 1, Students: 10 },
        2: { id: 1, Students: 22 }
    }
},
"251": {
    "Term 1": {
        0: { id: 1, Students: 2 },
        1: { id: 1, Students: 5 },
        2: { id: 1, Students: 10 }
    }
}
```

OUTPUT should be like - 
For 254 - Total count of student should be cumulative of all the term 101 
For 251 - Total count of student should be cumulative of all the term 17

254 and 251 is classID. So, in one class there are multiple terms and I need to fetch total student count for all the term in that class.

I tried using reduce but not getting expected output.

```js
this.progressReportList = data; // in this list I am getting data
this.progressReportList.reduce((acc, ele) => {
  console.log("ele : ", ele);
  return acc + parseInt(ele.Students);
}, 0);
```

Please advice!

Comment: `reduce()` only works on arrays, not objects. Do you have any control over the data structure? The logic can be made very simple if the original data is in an array

Answer (score 2):

Your structure means that you need to do multiple steps, including multiple calls to `Object.entries` / `Object.values` .... and there are also two `reduce` calls in there.

```js
const input = {
  254:{
    "Term 1":{   
         0:{id:1,Students: 29},
         1:{id:1,Students: 20},
         2:{id:1,Students: 11}
     },
     "Term 2":{   
         0:{id:1,Students: 9},
         1:{id:1,Students: 10},
         2:{id:1,Students: 22}
     }
  },
  251:{
    "Term 1":{   
         0:{id:1,Students: 2},
         1:{id:1,Students: 5},
         2:{id:1,Students: 10}
     }
  }
}

const result = Object.entries(input).reduce( (acc, [id,terms]) => {
    acc[id] = Object.values(terms) // Get all the terms
                    .flatMap(x => Object.values(x)) // flatten it out
                    .reduce( (sum, x) => sum += x.Students, 0); // sum the students
    
    return acc;
},{})

console.log(result)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use some Object API instead.

Like Object.keys(), Object.values() Or [Object.entries()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/entries)

```js
// iterate through key-value gracefully
const obj = { a: 5, b: 7, c: 9 };
for (const [key, value] of Object.entries(obj)) {
  console.log(`${key} ${value}`); // "a 5", "b 7", "c 9"
}

// Or, using array extras
Object.entries(obj).forEach(([key, value]) => {
console.log(`${key} ${value}`); // "a 5", "b 7", "c 9"
});
```

Answer (score 0):

***Observation :*** Your JSON object is not valid as per the object posted in a post. That might be a typo but I am just informing you.

***Solution :***
You can simply achieve that by using [`Object.keys()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Object/keys) to iterate over an nested object keys and with the help of [`Array.reduce()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/reduce).

Live Demo **:**

```js
const obj = {
  254:{
    "Term 1":{   
      0:{id:1,Students: 29},
      1:{id:1,Students: 20},
      2:{id:1,Students: 11}
    },
    "Term 2":{   
      0:{id:1,Students: 9},
      1:{id:1,Students: 10},
      2:{id:1,Students: 22}
    }
  },
  251:{
    "Term 1":{   
      0:{id:1,Students: 2},
      1:{id:1,Students: 5},
      2:{id:1,Students: 10}
    }
  }
};

const res = {};

Object.keys(obj).forEach(key => {
  res[key] = 0;
  Object.keys(obj[key]).forEach(k => {
    res[key] += Object.values(obj[key][k]).map(element => element.Students).reduce((a, b) => a + b , 0);
  })
});

console.log(res);
```